# If a div color has changed for 3 seconds, do something

Tags: javascript, animation

There is a chain animation for color changes on div, I want to do 'if div has not changed color for 3 secs, do something'
How do I check the time with the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you only call this function for changing the color:

```
var timeoutId;

function changeColor(el, col, secs) {
    if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    // change color logic
    el.style.backgroundColor = col;

    // check
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        alert('color has not changed within ' + secs + ' seconds');
    }, secs * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the question is "'if div has not changed color " The only way I know to test if an HTML element change an attribute value is to use a global timer that check every tot milliseconds. In this case....

Comment: And if the color is changed outside? That's my note, your answer is ok if we assume to use only your func. I pointed out that because in the last i had checked against attribute changing outside my control and the behaviour among browser is different with the change event.

Comment: I had to find other way to program the feature, but this answer helped for inspiration.